# Laravel 8.x - pass pivot table data to mailable

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a platform where students can apply for academic courses. When an application is sent, apart from  being saved into the database, it must fire an email with the information of the applicant along with the titles of the applied courses.

An Applicant can apply for many Courses, hence the pivot table Applicant_Course. The Applicant model:

```
    class Applicant extends Model
{

use HasFactory;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'fname',
    'lname',
    'email',
    'phone',
    'is_student',
];

public function courses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

The Mail\ApplicationMail:

```
public function __construct(Applicant $applicant)
{
    $this->applicant = $applicant;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    // return $this->view('view.name');
}
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to pass the Applicant object into the mailable. This is what the applicationMail view looks like:

```
<tr class="email-row">
                <td class="left-column"><b>Email: </b></td>
                <td class="right-column email-cell"> 
                    <a href="{{ $email }}">
                        {{ $email }}
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @isset($phone)
            <tr>
                <td class="left-column"><b>Phone: </b></td>
                <td class="right-column">
                    <td class="right-column subject-text">{{ $phone }}</td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endisset
            <tr>
                @foreach ($applicant->courses as $course)
                <div class="application-body-item">
                <p>{{$course->title}}</p>
                    <p>Course Code: {{$course->code}}</p>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
```

But the line where it says: '@foreach ($applicant->courses as $course)' returns the error: 'Undefined variable: applicant'.

Here is my ApplicationsController:

```
$input = $request->all();

    \Mail::send('applicationMail', array(

        'title' => $input['title'],
        'org' => $input['org'],
        'fname' => $input['fname'],
        'lname' => $input['lname'],
        'email' => $input['email'],
        'course-check' => $input['course-check'],
        'phone' => $input['phone'],
        'created_at' => $input['created_at'],
        'updated_at' => $input['updated_at'],

    ), function($message) use ($request){

        $message->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME'));
        $message->to(env('MAIL_USERNAME'))->subject($request->get('subject'));

    });
```

Any idea how to pass the Applicant's data into the mailable so that I can retrieve the pivot table data (from the Applicant_Course table) just like I do inside a normal view ?

Comment: You're not passing an `Applicant` instance in your array (`'applicant' => Applicant::find(...)`). Until you pass `'applicant' => ...` in that `array()`, you can't use `$applicant` in the view.

Comment: @TimLewis thank you, that was the solution! I can't believe I missed this

Comment: No problem! Another note, `Mail::send()` doesn't use Mailables; `Mail::to(...)->send(new ApplicationMail($applicant));` does 